# Some of my text fields and text areas cannot be clicked for data entry

Tags: css

After applying CSS to one of my forms, some of the fields cannot be accessed without tabbing to them. I am applying relative positions, padding, and float. What is the likely cause of this problem?

Comment: There is some CSS code that needs to be changed because it interacts with some field in a way that prevents them from being clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using positioning you might have positioned your form under some other element and now only click in that one instead on your form.

- Try to get it on the top layer.
  You can do that by specifying the z-index higher value.

  input {
  z-index:2;}
- Or move it somewhere else
  temporarily to see if it was under
  some other element.